# Как передать css свойство для текста в фотошопе?

Tags: css, вёрстка, шрифты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то стилями css задать свойства для текста (**Резкое | Четкое | Насыщенное | Плавное**) из Photoshop?

Пробую и `-webkit-font-smoothing` и `text-rendering` , но никакого эффекта (ничего не меняется, хотя в фотошопе результат заметен).

Comment: Леночка тут по графическим редакторам не задают вопросы ! Мой аналогичный вопрос висел неделю, мне так сказали и я удалил его

Comment: А тут не по графическому, а скорее по css и верстке!

Comment: Леночка в css вроде нету таких свойств , как размытие текста или чёткое или насыщенное или плавное ,webkit-font-smothing вы сами же понимаете что речь идёт только о webkit т.е о -moz- или -o- такого не будет , хм... скорее всего сам шрифт сыграет большую роль в вашей задаче, к примеру уменьшить его и придать font-weight - и будет то что надо

Comment: " css вроде нету таких свойств" потому и спрашиваю, а вдруг все-таки есть)))

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko тень + color: transparent? [Бэмс](https://css-tricks.com/examples/BlurredText/)